# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `open` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(Modal)`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

### I get a warning after applying code from Material UI Dialog component. App works fine but i want to solve the warning, do you know how can i solve it ?

here is a link to material ui component:
[https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/-=)

Note: before adding the dialog component everything worked fine.

Thanks in advance for everyone answering !

[image: Failed prop type, the prop open is marked as required in 'Forwardref(Popover)']

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import axios from "axios";
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import Slide from '@mui/material/Slide';

import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import {useState} from "react";

function Copyright(props) {
    return (
        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary" align="center" {...props}>
            {'Copyright © '}
            <Link color="inherit" href="https://mui.com/">
                Your Website
            </Link>{' '}
            {new Date().getFullYear()}
            {'.'}
        </Typography>
    );
}

const theme = createTheme();

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
    return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

export default function SignIn() {

    const history = useNavigate();

    const [dialogueMessage,setDialogueMessage] = useState('')
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setChecked(event.target.checked);
    };

    const [iopen, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
        const username = data.get('email').split("@")[0];
        if (checked === false ) {
            console.log("post")
            axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_HOST + "/users/login", {
                email: data.get('email'),
                password: data.get('password')
            }).then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp.data)
                history("/users/" + username,{state:{token:resp.data.token,email:data.get('email'),user_id:resp.data.item.id}})
            })
        }else{
            axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_HOST + "/admin/login", {
                email: data.get('email'),
                password: data.get('password')
            }).then((resp) => {
                if(resp.data.success === false){
                    handleClickOpen()
                    setDialogueMessage(resp.data.message)
                }else {
                    history("/admin/" + username, {state: {token: resp.data.token, email: data.get('email')}})
                }
            })

        }
    };




    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
                <Dialog
                    open={iopen}
                    TransitionComponent={Transition}
                    keepMounted
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
                >
                    <DialogTitle>{"There is a problem with your login !"}</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
                            {dialogueMessage}
                        </DialogContentText>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose}>Disagree</Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose}>Agree</Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
                <CssBaseline />
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        marginTop: 8,
                        display: 'flex',
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                >
                    <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
                        <LockOutlinedIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                        Log in
                    </Typography>
                    <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <TextField
                            margin="normal"
                            required
                            fullWidth
                            id="email"
                            label="Email Address"
                            name="email"
                            autoComplete="email"
                            autoFocus
                        />
                        <TextField
                            margin="normal"
                            required
                            fullWidth
                            name="password"
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            id="password"
                            autoComplete="current-password"
                        />
                        <FormControlLabel
                            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                            label="Remember me"
                        />
                        <Switch
                            checked={checked}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
                        />
                        Are you an admin ?
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                        >
                            Log In
                        </Button>
                        <Grid container>
                            <Grid item xs>
                                <div/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <Link href="/register" variant="body2">
                                    {"Don't have an account? Register"}
                                </Link>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
                {/*<Copyright sx={{ mt: 8, mb: 4 }} />*/}
            </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your code is bloated. You should work on a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example). On the way there, you might even find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, the API call has not yet resolved so you get the warning.  Eventually (if you see it), the data will populate after the API call is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue once I forget to initiate my open dialog state  which make sense cause living the state without initiating return the value `undefined`

```js
const [dialog, setDialog] = useState()
```

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `open` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(Dialog)`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

after initiating my state the issue dispear

```js
const [dialog, setDialog] = useState(false)
```